# In case I upload an unpublished conference paper or technical report of mine to Academia.edu is it protected from plagiarism?

Tags: plagiarism, online-publication, grey-literature

I would like to know if an uploaded unpublished paper of mine it is safe from plagiarism, including just parts of it (e.g. title).

I meant that if somebody copies part or the entire unpublished, but already online, document and publishes it, is he/she then liable of plagiarism?

Comment: What do you mean? Nothing is "safe from plagiarism". If I can read it, I can copy and paste it or retype it, change the name and republish it as my own. The only way to be safe is not publishing anything...

Comment: Did you mean can you upload an unfinished paper and hold a copyright on it?

Comment: I meant that if somebody copies part or the entire unpublished, but already online, document and publishes it, is he/she then liable of plagiarism?

Answer (score 3):

Liability for plagiarism does not depend on whether the plagiarized work was published or not.

If somebody uses your work and passes it off as their own work, it's plagiarism.